# Amazon S3 API .Net C# - Accessing external Bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access an external bucket over the Amazon S3 API through .Net / C#.

I already tried the login with a 3rd party tool which worked like a charm, now I want to get the items of the bucket inside the framework. I am using this behind a Proxy, that's why I am using the S3config.

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
                        {
                            CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP,
                            ProxyHost = Proxy.Host,
                            ProxyPort = Convert.ToInt32(Proxy.Port),
                            ProxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential
                                                {
                                                    UserName = Proxy.User,
                                                    Password = Proxy.Password
                                                }
                        };
AmazonS3 S3Client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey,S3Config);
```

that's the way I establish the connection itself to amazon. I also already tried placing

```
ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
```

into the config object initializer because I am in EU and the bucket is located somewhere in US.

When I now try to access via :

```
ListObjectsRequest req = new ListObjectsRequest { BucketName = "yelp-syndication" };
ListObjectsResponse resp = S3Client.ListObjects(req);
```

or

```
AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID);
return client.ListBuckets().Buckets.Where(b => b.BucketName == bucket).Single();
```

or

```
ListObjectsRequest Request = new ListObjectsRequest
                            {
                            BucketName = BucketName
                            };
ListObjectsResponse Response = S3Client.ListObjects(Request);
```

I only get Access Denied in the error object that is thrown.
The credentials I use are 100% the same as in the 3rd party tool.

Am I missing something here ? do I need to use any special way which I just can't find to make it work ?

a working python snippet is:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
 conn = S3Connection(<ACCESS_KEY_ID>, <SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
 bucket = conn.get_bucket(<BucketName>, validate=False)
```

this returns correct results, so the actual connection works and also the credentials.

Comment: I had the same problem, your service url needs http or https. Worked for me. The documentation is pretty poor in the sense that its wrong. IMO

Comment: I tried that already, if I add http:// to the serviceurl for the config and then ask the listobjects, it asks actually for: http://bucketnamehttp://s3.amazonaws.com and fails because this is obviously not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using the given answers as a new base for research I figured out, that I have to give a serviceurl, a regionendpoint and a communicationprotocol for the S3Config Class on the one side and, because I knew the exact name of the file within the bucket, I needed to use getobject and not an access to the bucket.

so the code that got me working is:

```
            AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config
                                  {
                                      ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
                                      RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2,
                                      CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTPS,
                                      ProxyHost = Proxy.Host,
                                      ProxyPort = Convert.ToInt32(Proxy.Port),
                                      ProxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential
                                                         {
                                                             UserName = Proxy.User,
                                                             Password = Proxy.Password
                                                         }
                                  };
        _S3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey, S3Config);
        _ObjRequest = new GetObjectRequest
                                      {
                                          BucketName = BucketName,
                                          Key = Key
                                      };
        _ObjResponse = _S3Client.GetObject(_ObjRequest);
        return (_ObjResponse != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I'm using to return a list of files in a "directory" in my bucket and I know it definitely works. I says directory but actually there isn't such thing. My understanding of S3 is each file/folder is an object. Each object has a key. Key determines where in the tree you will see a folder or file. A key Folder1 I believe will be a Folder called Folder1 at the route. An object with a key Folder1/File1.txt would be a file in Folder1.

If other clever people have more to say or corrections, I'm sure they will tell me. But, the code does work.

```
    public List<string> ListFilesIn(string folder)
    {
        //I get my values from Orchard CMS but as long as your credentials are correct and can access the bucket this should work a dream.
        var settings = new {S3ServiceUrl = "", S3SecretKey="", S3KeyId = "", S3BucketName = ""}

        var amazonS3Config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            ServiceURL = string.Format("https://{0}", settings.S3ServiceUrl)
        };

        folder += folder.Substring(folder.Length - 1, 1) == "/" ? "" : "/";

        using (var amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(settings.S3KeyId,
         settings.S3SecretKey,
         amazonS3Config))
        {

            var response = amazonS3Client.ListObjects(new ListObjectsRequest
            {
                BucketName = settings.S3BucketName,
                Prefix = folder
            });

            if (response.S3Objects.Count() > 0)
            {
                return response.S3Objects.Select(s => s.Key).Where(w=>w != folder).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, because it's key based, everything is case sensitive.